# How to prevent persistent XSS vulnerability with the Java Struts 1 Framework?

Tags: jsp, xss, struts

I have an application that executes under Tomcat 7, developed with Struts (Java Web Framework). My application contains a security vulnerability (XSS Cross-site scripting).

**What kind of XSS vulnerability is it ?**

- Persistent (or stored)

**How is it introduced and what is the context ?**

- Enter value in the textfield

**What Java frameworks are you using ?**

- Struts 1.3

XSS is performed by the HTML code, which was introduced by a third party and is performed by the application. In the following example shows the vulnerability:

[Form with button submit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovVg9.png)

[Script executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjGNG.png)

Here is the code JSP page of inputs:

```
<td>Descripción</td>
<td><html:text name="grupo" maxlength="50" property="description" size="30" alt="Descripción" /></td>
```

Here is the code JSP viewer page then submit:

```
<tr>
<td>Descripción</td>
<td><jsp:getProperty name="grupo" property="description"/></td>
```

Comment: Use `<c:out value="${enteredValue}">` to display the entered value.Do not use `${enteredValue}`: all strings coming from an external source must be properly html-escaped (that's what c:out does). The problem is in the code you didn't show: the code which displays the entered value.

Comment: I updated the code to displays the entered value :)

Comment: Do not, ever, use jsp:getProperty. This is really old stuff, that was already deprecated when Struts was a non-abandoned framework (i.e. more than 5 years ago. Use the JSP EL, and the JSTL as shown in my previaus comment.

Comment: Should I update the framework too or not?

Comment: You don't need to. But if you're starting a new web project, you should really, really not use Struts. It'a officially abandoned for 5 years. Use a modern, active, web framework.

Comment: I'd amend that to "don't use Struts 1". S2 is still actively maintained and moving forward. Wouldn't be my first choice, but it's acceptable.

Comment: My proyect is too long to make a migration, so i will choise to add jstl to it

Comment: I was able to add JSTL to the project, but now I need to change the input to not save the script in the database. I need help.